# Sidebar-Link Jenkins Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use Sidebar-Link Jenkins Plugin to publish report link at Jenkins job. As I am using Jenkins pipeline for creating jobs, I am not able to use this plugin. Could someone suggest me a better plugin which I can use for report link publish other than publishHTML plugin or provide pipeline wrapper script to use Sidebar-Link Plugin?

Comment: Both asking suggestions for off-site resources and asking to provide code are off topic for SO.

Comment: James, could you please explain?

Comment: I though that was quite clear, but... "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam": https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: properties( [addSidebarLink("Link Title", "/path/to/link/img", "http://link.url.including.${env.VARIABLES}")] )